# Coproduct On $top^*$

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to find the coproduct on $top^*$.

$top^*$ is a category with objects $(X,x_0)$ s.t $X$ is topological space and $x_0\in M$ and $Hom((X,x_0),(Y,y_0))=\{f \,| f :X\rightarrow Y$ , $f(x_0)=y_0$ and $f$ is continuous function $\}$
let $\{(A_i,x_i)\}$ be a family of objects , i guess coproduct for $\{(A_i,x_i)\}_{I}$ is $(P,\{\pi_i\}_{I})$ that $p=(K,(*,*))\,s.t\,K=\{(a,i)|\,a \in A_i , i\in I \} \cup\{(*,*)\}$ and $\pi_i \in Hom((A_i,x_i),p)$ .
 How can i prove this?
can somebody help me?

Comment: The coproduct is not what you wrote because your maps $\pi_i:A_i\rightarrow K$ do not preserve the base points, and thus are not map in $Top_*$. The coproduct is the wedge sum.

Comment: @Roland : thanks